# Show date with PST/CST etc. in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I have date 2012-04-02 10:01:00 am 
I want to show this date in with PST/CST at tail of this date like 2012-04-02 10:01:00 PST.

Is there any way to convert normal date into this format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  get this by adding T abbreviation, like:

```
 date('Y-m-d H:i:s T')
 //date('Y-m-d H:i:s T', strtotime('2012-01-12 12:30:45')); // for specific date
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is:
Have a look at functions here :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`DateTime::SetTimeZone()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php) to set the timezone to specific DateTime variable and then use [`DateTime::format`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) with proper format to get that value like you want it: `'Y-m-d H:i:s T'`